# jQuery/ css div doesn't remain visible/ always fade out

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

I've a container inside another container, wrapped in an overlay div.
All three containers have different z-indexes:

```
#overlay{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    _position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000;
    z-index:999;
}
#fuori{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:60%;
    z-index:1000;
}
#form_wrapper{
    position:relative;
    z-index:10001;
}
```

On a link click the containers are fading in with the following code:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.animatedForm', function () {
        $('#fuori').fadeIn("slow").center();// .center() = function for centering div
        $("#overlay").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        }).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    });
    $('#overlay,#fuori').on('click', function () {
        $('#fuori,#overlay').fadeOut("slow");

    });
});
```

The problem is: even if i'm clicking inside the #form_wrapper which
contains a couple of dynamic forms, the #form_wrapper and the other disappears, even if the z-indexes are correct.

I've tried also

```
$('#overlay,#fuori').not('#form_wrapper').on('click',function() {
```

and

```
$('#overlay,#fuori:not(#form_wrapper)').on('click',function() {
```

but nothing is working.

How write the code in the right way to keep alive the #form_wrapper?

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

**Edit**

@barbara laird

It's just a normal form

```
<div id="fuori">
<div id="form_wrapper" >

  <!-- form -->

 </div>

 </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Without reading this entire thing, this selector `#fuori:not(#form_wrapper)` is really weird. An ID should be 1:1, so there's no meaning of selecting an element with one ID but not another.

Comment: I just was trying out everything to get the code working :-)

Comment: Can you show your html markup?

Comment: According to your HTML, overlay neither contains, nor is contained by, the fouri or form_wrapper divs.

Comment: It's just there for overlaying the page, it should not contain anything.

Answer (score 0):

why not remove the #fuori selector from your click-fadeout event? your form will still be the same size as it (unless you specified form width elsewhere); so clicking on the form may also be triggering the event for #fuori.

Comment: In fact, it's working perfectly without it. But i need it for centering the form. Inside the #fuori div there are 3 forms with different sizes; they are switching beetween them on button click inside the form. e.g.: login, forgot password, register. I think the problem is to add a return false or something like that but i haven't found out yet where.

Comment: You are partially right: i had to add height:0; in the #fuori div for firefox; the only problem is IE: the container doesn't fadeIn anymore, it just jumps in, also with filter: inherit and display:inherit. I'm trying to working it out